# How to update widget from app activity, not from the widget activity?

Tags: android

I need MainActivity.java to update the widget. Ive been googling alot still can't figure it.

My widget has :

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[]   appWidgetIds)
{
...
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
...
}
```

Triggering any of these methods will help me.

Comment: post more code, where do you use your widget

Comment: Its a homescreen widget, Im sorry im new.